# How to render erubi template to html?

Tags: ruby, erb

As rails 5.1+ switched to `erubi` I tried to use that in ruby script:

```rb
require 'erubi'

template = Erubi::Engine.new("<%= test %>", escape: true)
```

However I'm stacked trying to render that template to html.

`erubi` source code: https://github.com/jeremyevans/erubi

`erubi` is fork of `erubis`, and in `erubis` the rendering is done via `result` method:

```rb
require 'erubis'

template = Erubis::Eruby.new("<%= test %>", escape: true)
template.result test: "<br>here" #=> "&lt;br&gt;here"
```

However there's no `result` method in `erubi`.

Comment: @sawa I've re-wrote the question.

Comment: Note that [`test` is a `Kernel` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-test) that expects 2 or 3 arguments, so it’s not a great example for sample code as it can throw unrelated errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the Erubi README](https://github.com/jeremyevans/erubi#usage) (it says “for a file” but it appears to mean “for a template”):

> Erubi only has built in support for retrieving the generated source for a file:
>
> ```
> require 'erubi'
> eval(Erubi::Engine.new(File.read('filename.erb')).src)
> ```

So you will need to use one of the `eval` variants to run from a standalone script.

```
template = Erubi::Engine.new("7 + 7 = <%= 7 + 7 %>")
puts eval(template.src)
```

Outputs `7 + 7 = 14`.

If you want to be able to use instance variables in your template as you might be used to from Rails, Sinatra etc., you will need to create a context object and use `instance_eval`:

```
class Context
  attr_accessor :message
end

template = Erubi::Engine.new("Message is: <%= @message %>")
context = Context.new
context.message = "Hello"

puts context.instance_eval(template.src)
```

Outputs `Message is: Hello`.

Answer (score 1):

In rails 5.1 I switched out the `Erubis::Eruby.new` code to the following:

```
ActionController::Base.render(inline: "<%= test %>", locals: {test: "<br>here"})
```

Rails will do the heavy lifting.

Comment: This worked perfectly, without having to create the context, thanks a lot!